# plt not increasing the size of the plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
df.plot(x='age', y='pledge_amount', style='o')
plt.show()
```

The dataframe df has age and pledge_amount columns, but the chart does not become larger if i change figsize.Is it because of the df.plot not connected to plt?

I tried :

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.plot(x=df.age, y=df.pledge_amount, style='o')
plt.show()
```

but nothing appears on the screen in this case.

Comment: Which aspect of the chart would you like to make larger? The plot markers, the fontsize of the labels, the extent of the axes? Markersizes are given in fraction of the axis size. So increasing the figure size does not change the appearance of the markers. However, you can set the size using the keyword `markersize` (or `ms`).

Comment: @PaulBrodersen, i want the whole chart to be bigger, usually we do it with figsize

Comment: should be `df.plot(x='age', y='pledge_amount', style='o',figsize=(8,8))`

Comment: also, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13/visualization.html) with some examples of going between pandas and matplotlib.